# System.Debug() appears to be summing additional logged values

Tags: apex, debug-logs, queueable-apex

I'm running the following code, and I just want to log the total amount of deletes, and the total amount of records passed into the method and return the total amount of records that were processed and the total amount of deletes. However, the **the debug logs appear to be adding these two numbers together.** what am I missing here?

**High Level Process**

Schedule Class --> Batch Class --> Queueable Class --> Managed Package Future Method Triggered by Update performed in Queueable Class

**Code: Queueable Class**

```
public with sharing class Queable_RemoveCustomers implements Queueable {


   List<Customer__c> customers = new List<Customer__c>();
   public Queable_RemoveCustomers(List<Customer__c> customers){
       this.customers = customers;
   }

   public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
       Integer totalDeletes = 0;
       Integer errors = 0;
       System.Debug('QUEUED UP');
       System.Debug('Customers ='  + customers.size());
       List<Database.SaveResult> updateResults = Database.update(customers, false);

            for (Database.SaveResult result : updateResults) {
                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    System.debug(result.getId());
                    System.debug(result.getErrors());
                    errors++;
                } else {
                    totalDeletes++;
                }
            }

        System.debug('DELETE Payload = ' + customers.size());
        System.Debug('SUCCESSFUL DELETES = ' + totalDeletes);
        System.Debug('FAILED DELETES = ' + errors);

    }

}
```

The output to the log is the following:

`Customers = 142
 DELETE Payload = 142
 SUCCESSFUL DELETES = 284
 FAILED DELETES = 0`

Comment: You say there is a managed package future method after the Queueable in your transaction chain, but your code sample seems to contradict that.

Comment: The update to the record triggers the future method. This future method is not something we have access to, but not sure it should have an impact on the different numbers here in the log...

Comment: You didn't over-simplify your code by chance, did you? The total number of records processed must equal the original list size. There's absolutely no way I know of that this could happen, so I presume you've cut out some code that would explain it.

Comment: since you are using allOrNothing = false; if there are any errors, SFDC will retry the DML on the successes; this could account for the variance in counts - see [Order of Execution, Additional Considerations, second bullet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm?search_text=order%20of%20execution) - I'm not convinced this is the issue but worth examining

Comment: I am passing the list size from a batch process. I just ran it again though, and the numbers did not double; I did not make changes to the code to fix the issue either. Have any of you ever seen this behavior.

Comment: Would it have anything to do with a batch class being stateful? The batch class that runs before and calls the queueable class, is running in a stateful context and passing the list of deletes to the queueable class.